# Find the parent div, given a div class as a string in Java

Tags: javascript

Edit: Sorry for being unclear. I want to use javascript code inside a java class. I have a driver that can execute js codes.

I want to write a function in Java, that will receive a string with a (html) div's class name, and return a string with its parent div's class name.

Something like this:

```
    public String getParent(String divName) { return (JSDriver) driver.execute("js code");}
```

How should I put the parameter divName inside the js code?

Comment: clarify what a div is please

Comment: JavaScript and Java are completely different languages. Which are you using? Java runs on the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) on a server, while JavaScript runs in a web browser such as Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: A div is an HTML construct that can have a "name" attribute. @ntrch you can use `var div = document.getElementByName(divName)`

Comment: One of your 2 tags should be the wrong one

Comment: The java tag is the wrong one, probably

Comment: If we look at the syntax of the example code, javascript is the wrong tag.

Comment: It should be completed with Javascript

Comment: So sorry, please look at the edit

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding. I meant to use both js and java in the same line of code. It worked out, in the end, thanks to @siva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example **HTML** Code

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
     <p>childDiv</p>
  </div>
```

Example **JS** code

```
function getParentClass(className)
{ 
   return document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0].parentNode.className;
}
```

you can use the method `getParentClass(yourClassName);`

In your case try running ::

```
public String getParent(String divName) {
   return (JSDriver) driver.execute(document.getElementsByClassName(divName)[0].parentNode.className);
}
```